# Starting a subprocess via python multiprocessing hangs

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing, pyaudio

I'm using pyAudio to listen to the audio device and do some "stuff" in the background while the main program continues to run.

I started out with a second script, but would like to consolidate into a single script for supportability. When I moved the functions in and use Process to start up the listener it simply hangs and never runs.

Here's the simplified snippets of code:

```
        def listener(self, q):
            CHANNELS = 2
            RATE = 44100
            INPUT_BLOCK_TIME = 0.05
            FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
            RATE = 44100
            INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK = int(RATE*INPUT_BLOCK_TIME)

            p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                        channels = CHANNELS,
                        rate = RATE,
                        input = True,
                        frames_per_buffer = INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
            q.put(os.getpid())
            import time
            time.sleep(300)


        def startListener(self):
            q = Queue()
            p = Process(target=self.listener, args=[q])
            p.daemon=True
            p.start()
            print q.get()
```

Now if I remove the following stream setup then I get the process ID back as expected:

```
           stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                        channels = CHANNELS,
                        rate = RATE,
                        input = True,
                        frames_per_buffer = INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
```

Is there something about multiprocessing and threading I am missing? Is this a bad idea? Should I stick with keeping the listener code in a separate script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, after posting I realized that this may not be a strictly python issue. Although the code is python it is running under the web2py framework. I tested outside of web2py and it works fine. I'm going to leave the question open and take the issue to the web2py mailing list. If I get a fix I'll post it here as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method for `pyaudio.open()` is:

```
__init__(self, PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input=False, output=False, input_device_index=None, output_device_index=None, frames_per_buffer=1024, start=True, input_host_api_specific_stream_info=None, output_host_api_specific_stream_info=None)
```

According to the Docs on their website. You don't seem to be setting a PA_manager which looks like a required parameter.